# Pasar de una vista a otra, para luego volver a la vista inicial sin perder el estado que tenia

Tags: javascript, vistas, backbone

Quiero saber si hay algo que pueda aprovechar de backbone que me permita pasar información de una vista a otra y luego volver a la vista que inicializo a la segundo, sin perder los datos cargados.

Esto sería:

Desde la vista1 llamo al router y llego a la vista2. Vista1 le paso parametros a vista2. Vista2 hace su trabajo (en mi caso buscar un registro) y se lo tengo que devolver a vista1, pero vista1 tiene que mantener todo el estado que venia manteniendo y de alguna forma (acá la duda) grabarse lo que vista2 le pase.

Ese es mi problema, no se que forma tengo de devolverle datos a vista1.

Answer (score 0):

Las vistas no tienen un estado propiamente tal. Más bien dependen de un modelo y lo que dibujan debiese ser obtenido de las propiedades del modelo. Como el modelo sí tiene un estado, cualquier mutación que quieras persistir debes hacerla sobre el modelo.

Antes de responder, voy a cambiarle nombre a tus variables:

- `vista1` se llamará `vistaPadre`
- Su constructor se llama `VistaPadreView`
- `vista2` se llamará `vistaHija`
- Su constructor se llama `VistaHijaView`

Si quieres que `vistaHija` tenga un estado, debes pasarle un modelo:

```
var Modelo1 = Backbone.Model.extend();
var VistaPadreView = new Backbone.View.extend();
var vistaPadre = new VistaPadreView({
     model: new Modelo1()
});
vistaPadre.render();
```

Ahora dices que la `vistaHija` es instanciada desde la `vistaPadre` . Esta segunda vista también debiera tener un modelo subyacente como para ejecutar un `fetch` sobre éste y así refrescar sus datos. Según la descripción de tu pregunta, la `vistaHija` hace un request que tú mismo has armado tal vez usando `jQuery.ajax`.

Lo que debieras hacer, en cambio, es declarar un modelo subyacente para la `vistaHija`. Ese modelo debiera tener como atributo `urlRoot` el endpoint hacia donde quieres consultar los detalles del registro:

```
var Modelo2= new Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/buscaregistro/';
});
```

De esa manera, al llamar a `fetch` dentro de `Modelo2`, si éste tiene un atributo `id`, se ejecutará una llamada ajax a `/buscaregistro/<id>`.

Dentro de la `vistaHija` debes tener asociado un evento a la acción de traerse los datos, obteniendo lo que quieres buscar (por ejemplo) mediante el valor de un input con id `#busqueda`. Por ejemplo:

```
var VistaHijaView = new Backbone.View.Extend({
  events: {
     'click .buscar': 'gatillaBuscar'
  },
  gatillaBuscar: function() {
    this.model.set('id', this.$('#busqueda').value());
    this.model.fetch().then(function(respuesta) {
       ...la respuesta contiene los detalles del registro...
    })
  }
});

var vistaHija = new VistaHijaView({
   model: new Modelo2()
});
vistaHija.render();
```

Entonces, supongamos que la `vistaPadre` instancia a la `vistaHija`, y desde ésta el usuario puede buscar un registro mediante su id y obtener los detalles para éste y pasárselos a la `vistaPadre`. **Lo correcto en realidad** sería pasarle los detalles a la instancia de `Modelo1` y reinstanciar `vistaPadre` pasándole este modelo, que ahora tiene sus propiedades anteriores **más** las que acabas de fijar dentro de `vistaHija`.

Ahora, para que `vistaHija` pueda modificar la instancia de `Modelo1` tendría que tener una referencia a éste. Esta referencia se la puedes pasar al instanciarla desde `vistaPadre`.

Redefinamos entonces `vistaPadre` añadiéndole un evento que instancie y renderee la `vistaHija` pasándole no sólo la instancia de `Modelo2` sino la instancia de `Modelo1` en los `attributes`.

```
var VistaPadreView=Backbone.View.extend({
   events: {
     'click #abrevistaHija': 'abrirVistaHija'
   }
   abrirVistaHija: function() {
      var vistaHija = new VistaHijaView({
         model: new Modelo2(),
         attributes: {
            modelo1: this.model
         }
      });
      vistaHija.render();
   }
});
```

Entonces, al renderear `vistaHija`, ésta tiene una referencia a la instancia de `Modelo1` accesible como `this.attributes.modelo1` (que dentro de la `vistaPadre` se accede como `this.model`)

El método `gatillaBuscar` de la vista 2 debiera entonces hacer:

```
  gatillaBuscar: function() {
    var _this = this;
    this.model.set('id', this.$('#busqueda').value());
    this.model.fetch().then(function(respuesta) {
     _this.attributes.modelo1.set('detalle_registro', respuesta.attributes);
     var vistaPadre = new VistaPadreView({
        model: _this.attributes.modelo1
     });
     vistaPadre.render();
    });
  }
```

Lo que habrás hecho entonces es, desde las vistas, mutar modelos. Los modelos conservan su estado. Cuando reinstancias `vistaPadre` desde `vistaHija` pasándole la referencia a la instancia de `Modelo1`, ésta tiene el nuevo estado de su modelo.

Juntando todo:

```
var Modelo1 = Backbone.Model.extend();

var Modelo2= new Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/buscaregistro/';
});

var VistaPadreView=Backbone.View.extend({
   events: {
     'click #abrevistaHija': 'abrirVistaHija'
   }
   abrirVistaHija: function() {
      var vistaHija = new VistaHijaView({
         model: new Modelo2(),
         attributes: {
            modelo1: this.model
         }
      });
      vistaHija.render();
   }
});

var VistaHijaView = new Backbone.View.Extend({
  events: {
     'click .buscar': 'gatillaBuscar'
  },
  gatillaBuscar: function() {
    var _this = this;
    this.model.set('id', this.$('#busqueda').value());
    this.model.fetch().then(function(respuesta) {
     _this.attributes.modelo1.set('detalle_registro', respuesta.attributes);
     var vistaPadre = new VistaPadreView({
        model: _this.attributes.modelo1
     });
     vistaPadre.render();
    });
  }
});


var vistaPadre = new VistaPadreView({
     model: new Modelo1();
});
vistaPadre.render();
```

## Un camino alternativo más corto:

Ni siquiera necesitas reinstanciar `VistaPadreView` porque ésta podrías haberla pasado a `vistaHija` dentro de los atributos. La instancia `vistaPadre` sigue existiendo aunque ya no esté en el DOM. Entonces si dentro de `vistaPadre` haces:

```
 var vistaHija = new VistaHijaView({
     model: new Modelo2(),
     attributes: {
        modelo1: this.model,
        vistaPadre : this
      }
 });
 vistaHija.render();
```

Luego podrías re-renderear la `vistaPadre` desde `vistaHija` si `gatillaBuscar` se definiera como:

```
gatillaBuscar: function() {
    var _this = this;
    this.model.set('id', this.$('#busqueda').value());
    this.model.fetch().then(function(respuesta) {
     _this.attributes.modelo1.set('detalle_registro', respuesta.attributes);
     _this.attributes.vistaPadre.render();
    })
  }
```

Como `_this.attributes.vistaPadre` es la instancia original de `vistaPadre` y ésta ya está asociada a la instancia de `Modelo1`, la mutación que hiciste sobre ese modelo ya estará incorporada cuando vuelvas a renderear `vistaPadre`.